# Custom Logging in Firebase Cloud Function Doesn't Work?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?gen=2nd) you should be able to print out logs as your cloud function executes. But ever since they changed to the new, quite complicated [Cloud Console logging app](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/), I am not able to see my custom log messages anywhere.

Here is a modified snipped from my cloud function:

```
const {
  log,
  warn,
  error,
} = require("firebase-functions/logger");
require("firebase-functions/logger/compat");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.createNewAccount = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {
  const userId = context.auth.uid;

  let newUser = {};

  console.log("THIS IS CONSOLE LOG!");
  log("THIS IS A LOG!");
  warn("THIS IS A WARNING!");
  error("THIS IS An ERROR!");

  return admin.firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .get()
      .then( (userDoc) => {
        const userData = userDoc.data();

        console.log("THIS IS CONSOLE LOG!");
        log("THIS IS A LOG!");
        warn("THIS IS A WARNING!");
        error("THIS IS An ERROR!");
        log(userData);

        let noErrors = false;

        if (noErrors) {
          // do nothing and continue
        } else {
          throw new functions.https
              .HttpsError(
                  "invalid-argument",
                  "This is a simulated error."
              );
        }
      })
  .then( () => {
        return {
          success: true
        };
      })
  .catch( (error) => {
    throw new functions.https
        .HttpsError(
            "invalid-argument",
            error.message
        );
  });
});
```

In my app I get back an error with 'This is a simulated error.' as expected, but the log doesn't contain any of the console.log, log, warn or error messages.

[image: lack of any log outputs here]

Even after a whole bunch of searching I was not able to find any of the log messages anywhere. Does anyone have experience using log messages with Firebase's new cloud function logging app?

Comment: Have you checked if your service account has the **Logs Writer** role (`roles/logging.logWriter`)? Is Cloud Logging API enabled as well?

Comment: @RobertG Sorry for the late response: We tried it enabling the logging API and specifically adding the logs writer tole to the service account, but it made no difference.